# Dropdown Menu Toggle not working on iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the below menu + toggle button works great on any browsers on Android but iOS....

I can click on the button then the menu will show up & hide right away after showing.

I used a lot of work-around & fix, disable touchstart in bootstrap.js or changing z-index of navbar. . . but it won't help me anyway with this problem.

The menu seems to show up after click the toggle button but I can't see anything. I have to touch the toggle button again as closing the menu & touch again to open the menu again.

You guy can have a check if you have iPhone at http://getheadsup.com/

Thank you for your concern about my problem.

```
 <div id="header-wrapper" class="header fadeIn">
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container-fluid row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html#top"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-footer">
                <a href='order.php' class='navbar-preorder'>PRE ORDER</a>
                <!-- hamburger icon -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed menu-btn">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar top-bar"></span>
                    <!-- <span class="icon-bar middle-bar"></span>-->
                    <span class="icon-bar bottom-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html#alexa">Alexa</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html#technology">Technology</a></li>
                        <li id="spin">
                            <a href="index.html#techspec">Tech Specs</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="index.html#faq">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="http://blog.getheadsup.com/">Blog</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem seems to be in the container (div.main-menu). it's positioned as fixed with no height or width.

try to add height and width to it.

```
#header-wrapper .navbar .container-fluid .navbar-collapse {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

this worked for me.

Comment: I'm tired, and could not find the error. Thank you =)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse main-menu">
```

The size is almost nothing, height = 1px.
Since it contains the menu, nothing get displayed.

I don't know what CSS is going in there, but to see it working just set it to **overflow: visible**

Thats probably a workaround as it might cause issues elsewhere.

To solve it the right way the container need to have its children participating in the layout flow (e.g: not doing position:absolute or float: right/left).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in iOS and fixed it by changing the button class `collapsed` to the following jQuery code:

```js
$('your_section_class').toggleClass('collapse')
```

Comment: Hi Yassine, welcome to SO! Could you clarify why this works? That way other people will actually understand what they are doing and learn from it, as opposed to just copy/pasting your solution.